# How would making a world copy/backup work in Java Beta 1.7.3 work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I currently play on a world for Minecraft Java Edition in which I started it in Beta 1.4, and updated versions each month until I got to Beta 1.7.3. I know that after this update things drastically change and biomes shift so I want to make a copy of the world that I could keep in Beta 1.7.3 and could possibly use in case the transition from Beta 1.7.3 to Official Release 1.0.0 causes a world corruption or something.

The problem is that even though I've looked online about how to make world copies/backups, all of the videos take place around Minecraft 1.7/1.8's update and I don't know if copying a Beta 1.7.3 world uses the same method, or if because those versions in the tutorial videos and my version that I play on are years apart that the coding makes the methods different for some reason.

I apologise if this is a dumb question, as I'm still quite new with computers, but I want to know if it uses the same method or not so I can be comfortable enough to try making world copies/backups and move on to Official Release 1.0.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minecraft has always used a single folder for a world, so you can just copy that anywhere and put it back where it was when you want to restore the backup. The only thing that I remember ever moving from the general Minecraft options to a world save is the difficulty, which used to be applied to all worlds.